# How to build an array, "Incorrect range height" error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been struggling with this code for quite a while now, what I'm trying to do is to get the information from a a single column from one sheet and set it as notes in another sheet for example. the content from C2 on "Sheet1" should go as a note on "F2" on sheet "report" as a note (A note <kbd>Shift+F2</kbd> not a comment <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+M</kbd>).

So far I have this:

```
function insertPhoneNumbers() {
    //I'm still working on this I have not been able to make this work//
    //Ideally this will put the phone numbers as comment's in the needed cases//
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("report");
    var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var nrange = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 3, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 1)
    var sourcenotes = [nrange.getValue()]
    var notes = targetsheet.getRange(2, 6, sourcesheet.getLastRow(),1)
    notes.setNotes([sourcenotes]);
}
```

But its giving me an error while debugging "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 75" the range is actually 73 rows deep so I don't know what to do.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to get the column values from source sheet and add the values array as a note in the target sheet for a range of values. Please explain clearly, what do you want to achieve if my explanation is not correct.

Comment: Your explanation is correct get the values from a column range paste it as notes in the target range

Comment: Do you mean by adding the whole column range as a note to the target range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below to get the source range and add them as note in the target sheet:

```
function insertPhoneNumbers() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("cancel");
 var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("regis");
 var nrange = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 3, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 1)
 var sourcenotes = nrange.getValues()
 //Logger.log(sourcenotes);
 var notes = targetsheet.getRange(2, 6, sourcesheet.getLastRow(),1)
 notes.setNotes(sourcenotes);

}
```

Let me know if that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Yup, that did it, only thing is that copies it with a weird format but couple more lines of code and should fix it.